# Netlogo - spacing resources across world

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to distribute resources in a way that I can specify the number of resources and make sure that they have at least one patch between them.

In this example, the resources are being distributed across a set of hex tile turtles built on the underlying patch framework and tied together by links.

```
set-default-shape resources "resource stone" [
  ask n-of 10 tiles with [not any? resources in-radius 2] [
   hatch-resources 1 [
    set color brown
]]]
```

I cannot seem to get this to work and I think it is because the resources are not yet created in order to calculate the "not any?" bit.

[image]

Comment: The hexagons are turtles which are ignored in this part of the code?  And the patches are the normal square patches (as opposed to hexagon patches as in the Hex Cells Example in the Models Library)?  I'm just trying to understand better what you're trying to do.

Comment: `radius` is counted in patches, so it matters how big the patches are relative to the hexagons.

Comment: I see that now and my code has evolved to ignore patches...code in question updated.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with "I think it is because the resources are not yet created in order to calculate the "not any?" bit". So how about:

```
repeat 10 [
  ask one-of patches with [not any? resources in-radius 2] [
    ...
  ]
]
```

Comment: With updated code (above), it errors "ASK expected input to be an agent...NOBODY instead." To the other comment (Mars)...I am trying to do this, ideally, based on the topological relationship but I understand the network primitives are not ready for prime time.

Comment: Well, apparently you ran out of patches satisfying the conditions. Try a lower number than 10, or a smaller radius, or make a world with more patches?

Comment: I can see how lowering the repeat, reducing the radius, and making the world bigger all help. However, for my constraints (i.e. desiring a density of resources 2.5:1 or 40 tiles:16 resources), the code is unreliable. Expanding the world simply spreads my tiles out in a way that is unrealistic for my model. I will say though this code snippet does solve my original question: separating the resources our amongst the tiles